# How to scale a SVG in <img> WITHOUT modifying the SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to render an SVG with an `<img>` tag, scaled to a certain size. But approaches like modifying the `<img>`'s `width` and `height`, putting the `<img>` in a fixed-size div and setting `width: 100%`, etc., are not working. They only crop the SVG instead of scaling it.

```html
<img src="logo.svg" width="60px" height="30px">

<div style="width: 60px; height: 30px">
  <img src="logo.svg" width="100%">
</div>
```

All StackOverflow questions I could find say to just modify the SVG itself—change the `viewbox`, etc. But this is infeasible or undesired when you're referencing an external SVG, an SVG that's part of your company's shared library, etc.

How can I scale this rendered SVG without modifying the SVG itself?

Comment: an img should auto create a viewBox so this should just work. We'd need a [mcve] to see exactly why this isn't working for you.

Comment: Why is changing the viewbox undesirable? It's not the easiest way to scale the svg?

Comment: @GetSet Suppose you have an SVG used throughout your team's product. The way I understand it, changing the viewbox in the source SVG will affect all instances of that SVG, not just yours.

Comment: I see. If its just a one off svg or just a few, would it be possible to duplicate the ones you need to a location in your source that can change dynamically or as needed? A bandaid workaround for now, that is.

Comment: @GetSet It's possible for now. But relying on a copy of the source SVG is dangerous long-term, as it won't pick up changes in the source. Yet a script/workflow to autogenerate this copy seems overkill. Ideally I'd want a more robust solution.

Comment: Are you just trying to zoom and pan? Does `object-fit` and `object-position` not accomplish this? Also, how an SVG gets cut off _is_ part of the SVG declaration itself, so not much you could probably do there. You could also fetch the SVG yourself and process the code inline, but that might cause `CORS` issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can take over the role of the `<img>` with ***your own*** native Web Component `<svg-scale>`

- Load the external SVG with a fetch call
- read `factor` styling from *attribute*
- Put the SVG String into a shadowDOM to prevent any ID/Style bleeding

```html
<svg-scale src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></svg-scale>
<svg-scale factor=".5" src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></svg-scale>
<svg-scale factor=".75" src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></svg-scale>
<svg-scale factor="1.2" src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></svg-scale>
```

[image]

```html
<style>
  svg-scale {
    background: lightgreen;
    width: 140px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-scale", class extends HTMLElement {
    async connectedCallback() {
      let svg    = await (await fetch(this.getAttribute("src"))).text();
      let factor = this.getAttribute("factor");
      this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
          .innerHTML = `<style>svg{transform:scale(${factor})}</style>` + svg;
          
      // this.svg = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("svg");
      // console.log(this.svg.getAttribute("viewBox"));
      // do whatever you want
    }
  })
</script>

<svg-scale src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></svg-scale>
<svg-scale factor=".5" src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></svg-scale>
<svg-scale factor=".75" src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></svg-scale>
<svg-scale factor="2,.5" src="//load-file.github.io/heart.svg"></svg-scale>
```